# SVG graphics appear as generic "missing" icons in iOS (only)

Tags: ios, svg

**Summary:**
SVG images in Safari appear as generic 'image missing' icons

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Go to this page: http://www.brianwatsonphoto.co.uk/BrianWatsonTest/360/pages/Harbour.html

Scroll to bottom of page

**Expected Results:**
Ten navigation buttons (SVG images) appear as meaningful graphics

**Actual Results:**
Ten navigation buttons (SVG images) appear as "?" icons

**Regression:**

Occurs with these iOS browsers:
Safari 4.3.3,   Atomic Web 5.7.0,   iCab Mobile 4.8.4,   Terra 1.3,   iChromy 1.1

**Notes:**

These images load correctly with Mac OS X 10.6.7 and with IE Windows (and until recently on iOS: I have not changed anything in the code recently).

**Example page:**

http://www.brianwatsonphoto.co.uk/BrianWatsonTest/360/pages/Harbour.html

**Error console**

In Mac Safari in iOS 10.6.7 shows, for all SVG images:

"Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml"

In iOS shows no errors despite images not being displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

For Opera the files are sent as text/plain, so I guess this could be the server sniffing browsers and snding different mime types

Comment: Yes, the server is misconfigured. See e.g http://www.brianwatsonphoto.co.uk/BrianWatsonTest/360/pages/images/movemode.svg. That should be served as "image/svg+xml" but isn't at the moment.

Comment: That's very helpful, and gives me some ammunition to fire at somebody. Many thanks,